# Default item of a Layer Control

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to use Leaflet Layers Control with base layers, as in the [docs's example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/)... And it **is not working**

### REAL CASE:

```
var bing_options = {
    bingMapsKey: BING_KEY,
    attribution: attribMapBase+' BING',
    culture: 'pt'
};
var 
  lay_mapbox = L.tileLayer(MAPBOX_URL+MAPBOX_KEY, {
    attribution: attribMapBase+' MapBOX',
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
  }),
  lay_bing = L.tileLayer.bing(bing_options)
;

var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
    center: [-23.56149,-46.655953],
    zoom: 20,
    layers: [lay_mapbox, lay_bing]
});
L.control.layers({
    "Standard": lay_mapbox,
    "BING": lay_bing
}).addTo(mymap);
lay_mapbox.addTo(mymap); //  set as default... NOT WORKING!
```

Please see the use of the last command, it is not working.

Comment: `baseMaps['Grayscale'].addTo(map);`

Comment: oh, and BTW please don't comment on 5-year-old Leaflet issues on github.

Comment: Same answer as on the linked dup - the control picks up the layers that are added to the map when you add the control. If that's not elegant enough for you, you could extend the control.

Comment: Hi @IvanSanchez, please check my "real case", not working with your clues.

Comment: Hi @peeebeee, I edited, it is not only a elegancy problem, it is not working... I included a "REAL CASE" to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your real case [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is now possible to understand your issue and provide you with help relevant to your exact situation.

So let's see the mentioned [docs / tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/): (emphasis mine)

> Also note that when using multiple base layers, **only one of them should be added to the map at instantiation**, but all of them should be present in the base layers object when creating the layers control.

Now let's see the docs about [`layers`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-layers) map instantiation option:

> Array of layers that will be added to the map initially

So when you do:

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
  center: [-23.56149,-46.655953],
  zoom: 20,
  layers: [lay_mapbox, lay_bing] // Offending line
});
```

...you are actually adding *multiple* base layers to your map. Since they are *already* on map, `lay_mapbox.addTo(mymap)` does not change anything.

Simply do not add all of them initially, then you can selectively choose which one should be visible at start up:

```js
var
  lay_mapbox = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }),
  lay_bing = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  });

var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
  center: [-23.56149, -46.655953],
  zoom: 20,
  // layers: [lay_mapbox, lay_bing] // Offending line
});
L.control.layers({
  "Standard": lay_mapbox,
  "BING": lay_bing
}, null, {
  collapsed: false
}).addTo(mymap);
lay_mapbox.addTo(mymap); //  set as default
```

```css
html,
body,
#mapid {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-+ZaXMZ7sjFMiCigvm8WjllFy6g3aou3+GZngAtugLzrmPFKFK7yjSri0XnElvCTu/PrifAYQuxZTybAEkA8VOA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Now what *may* have misled you is that in the mentioned tutorial, the example uses the map `layers` option to initially add 1 base layer and 1 overlay:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [39.73, -104.99],
  zoom: 10,
  layers: [grayscale, cities] // 1 base layer, 1 overlay
});
```

...whereas the Layers Control is supplied with 2 base layers, 1 of them being in common with the above initially added layers:

```
var baseMaps = {
  "Grayscale": grayscale, // Initially added to the map
  "Streets": streets // Left alone
};

var overlayMaps = {
  "Cities": cities // Initially added to the map
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```